How to disable the cron jobs created by my module?
Anybody have crontab.xml reference of magento2.
I want to temporarily disable the custom cron job. I dont want to disable my module or delete it.

There are many ways to disable the corn jobs temporarily.
Method 1: Commenting out the cronjob
You can disable a cron job in Magento 2 by commenting out the cron job configuration in your module's crontab.xml file.
Example:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <!--
        <job name="custom_cronjob" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Job" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        -->
    </group>
</config>

Method 2: Updating the cron schedule configuration options

Log in to the Magento 2 admin panel.
Navigate to Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron (Scheduled Tasks).
Under the Cron configuration options for the group: [group name], find the cron job you want to disable.
Set the Generate Schedules Every field to 0.
Click Save Config.

This will disable the cron job. To enable it again, you can set the Generate Schedules Every field back to its original value.
Please note that this method might not work for all cron jobs, especially if they are not part of a group or if they are defined in a way that bypasses these settings.
Method 3: Schedule on a time which never comes (* * 31 2 *)
A cron expression that will never run can be created by setting a time that is impossible to reach. For example, you can set the day of the month to 31 and the month to February. Since February never has 31 days, this cron job will never run.
Example :
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="custom_cronjob" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Job" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * 31 2 *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>

Method 4: Creating store configuration
You can create a configuration setting in the Magento 2 admin panel to control whether your cron job should run or not. This involves creating a system.xml file for your module to add a new configuration field, and then checking this configuration value in your cron job's execute method.
Here's how you can do it:

Create a system.xml file in your module's etc/adminhtml directory with the following content:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="your_section">
            <group id="your_group">
                <field id="enable_cron" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enable Cron Job</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>

This will add a new "Enable Cron Job" configuration field in the Magento 2 admin panel under Stores > Configuration > Your Section > Your Group. The field will be a dropdown with "Yes" and "No" options.

In your cron job's execute method, check the value of this configuration setting before running the rest of the code:

namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Job
{
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $isEnabled = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('your_section/your_group/enable_cron', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        if ($isEnabled) {
            // Your cron job code here
        }
    }
}

This will prevent the cron job from running if the "Enable Cron Job" configuration setting is set to "No".

Good answer. Thanks.

If it is what you are looking for, please upvote or accept the answer. If any questions please ask them here related to the question. Thanks.

Disable Cron Job in Magento 2
To disable the cron job in Magento 2 you have to first create your module and rewrite the same cron job in your module’s crontab.xml file.
Let’s say I want to disable the cron job called module_cron_name which is defined in the Orange_Notify module. To disable this cron job create crontab.xml file under your custom module and change the schedule value to 0 0 30 2 *.
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
    <job name="module_cron_name" instance="Orange\Notify\Model\Notify" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 0 30 2 *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
</config>

By doing this we are telling Magento to run module_cron_name cron job at 00:00 on the 30th of February – at the date which will never happen. That means this cron job will never run.
This all are ways only to disable cron.becuase cron is executing based on cron group.

----------------------------Alternative ----------------------------------
You can not disable cron.
If 3rd party module using custom cron group then you can increase cron time from admin.


Thanks for the answer
